# Octave; Plot Transformation Curve for Histogram Equalization

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, octave

Matlab has this [command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/histeq.html):

```
[J,T] = histeq(I);
```

> `[___,T] = histeq(___)` also returns the transformation T that maps the gray component of the input grayscale image

I use `GNU Octave, version 6.4.0`. But the `histeq` [command](https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/histeq.html) of Octave does not have that output argument. How I can obtain the transformation of `histeq` and plot it in Octave?

Comment: this question looks **very familiar**. you asked this before. why did you delete the question? you were given the suggestion to get MATLAB (free trial) and somehow look at the source code of `histeq()` which I presume is written in matlab script. -- Octave is an open source project. you can contribute features and you can file issues.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That question was closed as off-topic. So I deleted that and ask it here. I have not enough space for installing trial of MATLAB. Also I have to find a way quickly!

Comment: If you read the source code for Octave's `histeq()` (using `edit`), I think you're looking to plot `Icdf`.

Comment: @beaker Thank you. I could plotting that. Please add your comment as answer, so I can accept it and it may be useful for others.

Comment: And please please please, if you choose to look at the source code of histeq, DO NOT then attempt to make a contribution to Octave.  As part of the contributor agreement:  "Your contribution must be an independent work or derived from code that may be released under the terms of the GPL.  Under no circumstances may it be based on code from Matlab or other non-free code that you may have access to view."  The project has had to delete contributions in the past that suggested they were inspired by Matlab source code.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping **T** is given by the cdf of the normalized histogram (see [Histogram equalization implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization#Implementation)).

This mapping is stored in the variable `Icdf` in `histeq.m`. Since the code for this function (aside from input checking) is only 6 lines, it would be a simple matter to clone the function to access **T**.